# How to delete ď»ż character from file a file with no extension - Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, file, io

So I have an assignment (Python 2.7) to process a file with no extension. It has a date in its first line :

```
2016.03.22.
```

But when I read it from file, and print it out, I get: `ď»ż2016.03.22.`

This does not happen when the extension is .txt, but I cant use that. I've tried this regex:

```
def checkDate(line):
    return re.search('(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.)', line)
```

For some reason it does not find it, returns None. I've tried http://www.pyregex.com/ and it sees the pattern without the odd character.

Is there any method to cut it down, without writing the whole file?

Comment: First, apply `r` for the string as in `re.search(r'(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}q.)', line)`, second I cannot see any `q` in your example string so obviously, there won't be a match.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo here, but checked with this on pyregex: `'(\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.)'`. What is the role of `r`?

Comment: Python doesn't care about file extensions. If you're seeing random extra characters in one of your files, but not in another one with a different name, your files are not the same. You may be creating your files with a text editor like `notepad.exe` that adds some extra bytes to the front of the file to indicate what byte-order or encoding you're using.

Comment: @MattSom: It makes the string "raw", thus no escape sequences are interpreted.

Comment: @Blckknght You are right. Recreated the file, and the character is not there now. Must have been notepad, I've used that, sure. Thanks a lot.